# Error while importing file txt

Tags: c++

I have an issue regarding import simple text (it is a book's exercise). I am able to export vector's value of custom type `Point` but I am not able to read them back and store them in another vector. I have run many times trying to understand which could be the cause and I saw that in the `while` loop the program builds the vector but when it comes to end it gives to me a `run_time_error`. I guess it does not recognize the end of file. These are my files:

Header file:

```
class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point();
    Point(int x1, int y1);
    int get_x() const { return x; }
    int get_y() const { return y; }
    void print_all(const vector<Point>& pv);
    void import_all(vector<Point>& pv);
    Point operator=(const Point& p);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p);
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p);
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Point>& p);
```

Source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "wfile.h"

Point::Point()
    : x{ 0 }, y{ 0 } {}

Point::Point(int x1, int y1)
    : x{ x1 }, y{ y1 } {}

Point Point::operator=(const Point& p)
{
    x = p.get_x(); y = p.get_y();
    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
    return os << '(' << p.get_x() << ','
        << p.get_y() << ')' << endl;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Point>& p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ")" << " "
            << "X: " << p[i].get_x() << " " << "Y: " << p[i].get_y() << endl;
    }

    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)
{
    int x, y;
    is >> x >> y;
    if (!is) 
    {
        error("Bad input.");
        is.clear(ios::failbit);
        is.unget();
        return is;
    };

    p = Point(x, y);

    return is;
}

void Point::print_all(const vector<Point>& pv)
{

    cout << "Please enter file output name: " << endl;
    string oname;
    cin >> oname;
    ofstream ost{ oname };
    if (!ost) error("Can't open output file.", oname);

    for (int i = 0; i < pv.size(); ++i)
    {
        ost << pv[i].get_x() << " " << pv[i].get_y() << endl;
    }
}

void Point::import_all(vector<Point>& pv)
{

    cout << "Please enter file input name: " << endl;
    string iname;
    cin >> iname;
    ifstream ist{ iname };
    if (!ist) error("Can't read file, ", iname);
    while (true)
    {
        Point p;
        if (!(ist >> p)) break;
        pv.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

Main file:

```
// Work with external files.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "wfile.h"


int main()
{
    Point p;
    vector<Point> original_points;
    vector<Point> processed_points;

    cout << "Please enter 7 pairs of numbers: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i)
    {
        cout << "#" << i + 1 << " pair: ";
        cin >> p;

        original_points.push_back(p);
    }

    p.print_all(original_points);

    cout << original_points << endl;

    p.import_all(processed_points);

    cout << processed_points << endl;

    keep_window_open();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your Point type look like? structs and classes do not inherently support stream insertion/extraction operations (<< and >>, respectively). In the print_all method, you are specifically inserting the x and y values into the stream. in order to use >> to read the Point x and y values, you will need to overload the >> operator on the Point type, or first read in the x and y values separately, then store them in the Point

Comment: You stated you get a run-time-error.  But there should be more to the error message.  What line does it occur on?  what is the full text of the error?

Comment: @youngmit Yep I overloaded the needed operators. I preferred to do not put them into the post trying to be not messy.

Comment: @abelenky I have performed a check and I saw that the error is inside the `while` loop. It seems it does not recognize when inputs are ended and it does not break the loop, e.g. it does not read properly `if (!(ist >> p)) break;`. This is because adding a `cout` and checking at every iteration it prints imported values!

Comment: @LeonardoUrbano They are needed though because you might have made a mistake with them.  Please **[edit]** your post to have an [mcve]

Comment: @NathanOliver done. Thanks

Comment: Your extraction operator is clearing the failure bit of the stream. In a word: *don't*. Think about what that means to the caller when they receive back a reference to the stream object with the formerly-failed state wiped clean.

Comment: @WhozCraig should I delete it? I have just taken a part of book code because it is my first time handling this kind of I/O file stuff.

Comment: I see no reason *either* of those operations should be there (the failure bit clear *or* the `unget`). And your `main` should be checking the stream extraction in that for-loop; not assuming it works.

Comment: @WhozCraig done! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not fix your problem but there are a few things wrong with your code. When you overload the extraction operator you should not be clearing any error in the overload and instead pass them out of the function.  With that you `operator >>` should be:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)
{
    is >> p.x >> p.y;  
    return is;
}
```

Now if there is a problem with the stream extraction the `istream` object will be in an error state and you can handle that in your calling code.

The next issue is the way you are reading from the file.  When you read from a file you should use the stream extraction operation to control the loop.  The advantage of that is if there is an error it will not loop again and once you reach the end of file it will not loop again.  So with that you need to change `import_all()` to:

```
void Point::import_all(vector<Point>& pv)
{
    cout << "Please enter file input name: " << endl;
    string iname;
    cin >> iname;
    ifstream ist{ iname };
    if (!ist) error("Can't read file, ", iname);
    Point p;
    while (ist >> p)
    {
        pv.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

Third now that if there is an error extracting a `Point` from the stream you can check to make sure there wasn't a read error before we use the point.  To do that you can change you for loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i)
{
    cout << "#" << i + 1 << " pair: ";
    cin >> p;
    if(!cin)  // cin is in an error state
    {
        cout << "invalid point entered.  Please enter a valid point." << endl;
        cin.clear(); // clear the error flags
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');  // empty stream of bad input
        i--; // decrement i so we loop back to asking for the same input
    }
    else  // extraction worked so store the point
        original_points.push_back(p);
}
```

To use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` you need to `#include <limits>`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I have another question regarding error handling.. To handle errors should I create a function e.g. `bool is_point(const Point& p) {...}` and let it check if input is valid in `int main()` right? Is that what you meant?

Comment: @LeonardoUrbano I would just check to make sure the stream extraction works.  I edited my answer to include how to validate the points that are being inputed

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me! It is very useful